# jQuery event triggering multiple times because of multiple javascript inclusions/requires

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem here and it's making me mad. I maintain a legacy php system. It's badly organized, no frameworks are used and a lot of other problems, for example, at least 5 different query versions are used in different parts of the system.

So my problem right now is this, I have a search form, when a button is clicked it shows a list of items, lets call this a list of "A" objects. In each A item, there is an expand /toggle button to show the B items that belong to A (this is done using ajax, by setting a specific div's html to the ajax response). Then each B also has an expand/toggle button to show the C items that belong to B.

What is happening: I click to search, all A are shown. I click on the expand to show the B items of one A object, they are shown. I click B to hide it, it hides and then show again. If I click it one more time, it hides, shows and hide. So it is like every ajax request is including the javascript code and running it.

I think this is pretty much an organization problem, I am not knowing how to include/require and insert the js correctly. I've been trying to solve this issue since yesterday and I think I've seen the code so many times that I can't think out of the box.

So here's some of the organization (I changed the names because there are some business rules):

SearchResults.php -> Declares a class that has static methods to print out HTML of each item A, B and C and some other helper methods. To make stuff "work", it has a require "js.php"; otherwise the A expand button does not work because it does not exist at the time the js is executed and no function is bound.

search.php -> the HTML form with all the search options, nothing important.

js.php -> the javascript stuff, why is it in a ".php"? I can't even remember, but I think it is because with the php I can require/include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../util/js/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

jQ(document).ready(function() {

  jQ(".loadBfromA").click( function(e) {

    if (div.style.display == 'none')
       alert("was hidden, now is showing");
       //call ajax_B.php
       //response is put into the div using .html(data)

    else
       alert("was showing, now is hidden");
    ...
```

ajax_B.php -> the ajax that access the database and echoes html code that will be put into the A items div. Here I have to require SearchResults.php, because I call some methods of the class.

Why is it including the jQ(document).ready being executed multiple times? How can I fix it? Is there any way I can reorganize the code?

Is the ajax_B.php, when requiring SearchResults.php, including the js again because SearchResults.php requires js.php? Does this gets echoed and then put into the div?

I can't make a fiddle of this because there is ajax included.

Edit:

I have tried unbind("click").bind("click", ())  and it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried $(document).off() ?

Comment: @sushant No, what does it do and where should I put it? before the .ready?

Comment: Put it before the .ready and it still fire multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the event is being bound multiple times on `jQ(".loadBfromA")`

I know this is not the cleanest solution out there, but you could rewrite the actual binding:

```
jQ(".loadBfromA").bind('click.loadbfroma', function(e) {
    // Do your code
    $(this).unbind('click.loadbfroma');
});
```

That way you can at least be sure that only one event is bound at all times, no matter how many times the code snippet is being included. I know this doesn't really help you with the underlying issue but it's a start.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to add to the question, I tried with that and the off() function and both did not work. I'll add it. I can't understand why it doesn't work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried tracing how many times the event is being fired? A console.log('message whatever') inside of the click event will let you trace if it's being shot off multiple times on click or not.

Comment: Yes I have, and it does fire multiple times.

Comment: Ok, let me edit my initial post and see if unbinding it inside of the click event helps.

I'm not entirely sure however if your code requires the click event to remain bound on the element after use though.

Comment: I'll just put in a working state right now. I had to change because of the firefox thingy where you have to pass the event as parameter to the onclick html attribute. Changed it all from listeners to on click without the preventDefault().